# re.sub выводит не то что задумывалось(python3.6.1)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

re.sub выводит не то что задумывалось
Снизу пример кода

```
import re
i=input() #H:\build\exe.win32-3.4\collections введите эту строку
print(re.sub(r"\w+",i,"f"))
```

Я понял что нужно писать с двойными слешами но я думаю пользыватель который будет вводить путь не будет ставить два слеша ибо он об этом просто не будет знать.
По сути должен выводить H:\build\exe.win32-3.4\collections а

выводит Huild\exe.win32-3.4\collections

**Почему это происходит и как это исправить?**

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли экранировать слэши ("\") и вопрос к регулярным выражениям не имеет отношения...

Comment: вы действительно пытаетесь заменить в строке `f` каждое слово на путь???

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Как раз в данном случае вопрос имеет отношение именно к регулярным выражениям, хотя пример, конечно, нелепый.

Comment: Ответ про удвоение дан уже, но чтобы ПРАВИЛЬНО видеть возвращаемую строчку набирайте ее в интрпретаторе БЕЗ PRINT, тогда бы сразу увидели в начале `'H:\x08uil'`....  Правда, когда возвращается None его как раз без принта не видно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В шаблоне замены необходимо удвоить знаки обратной клосой черты:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r"\w+",r"H:\\build\\exe.win32-3.4\\collections","f"))
                        ^^     ^^             ^^
```

См. [онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/piqqFn).

Знак обратной косой черты является специальным знаком в шаблоне замены, с его помощью задаются обратные ссылки на значения подмасок, поэтому, чтобы задать буквальный символ обратной косой черты, он должен быть удвоен.

Если шаблон замены является переменной величиной без обратных ссылок,  удваивайте буквальный символ обратной косой черты с помощью `.replace("\\", r"\\")` (т.е. замените один буквальный обратный слеш на два):

```
import re
i = r"H:\build\exe.win32-3.4\collections"
print(re.sub(r"\w+",i.replace("\\", r"\\"),"f"))
# => H:\build\exe.win32-3.4\collections
```

См. [ещё одно демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/JlRJ9A)

Comment: "Знак обратной косой черты является специальным знаком" не только в регулярных выражениях.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Не путайте обчные *буквальные* строки с шаблонами, используемые в `re.sub`.  В данном случае речь идёт о том, что для того, чтобы заменить что-то с помощью регулярного выражения на строку, содержащую символ обратной косой черты, буквальный ``\`` должен быть удвоен.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я немного изменил вопрос

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я немного изменил вопрос

Comment: @Gleb Ничего не изменилось: необходимо удваивать буквальный символ обратной косой черты.